# Python regex - Replace bracketed text with contents of brackets

Tags: python, regex, string, substitution, backreference

I'm trying to write a Python function that replaces instances of text surrounded with curly braces with the contents of the braces, while leaving empty brace-pairs alone. For example:

`foo {} bar {baz}` would become `foo {} bar baz`.

The pattern that I've created to match this is `{[^{}]+}`, i.e. some text that doesn't contain curly braces (to prevent overlapping matches) surrounded by a set of curly braces.

The obvious solution is to use `re.sub` with my pattern, and I've found that I can reference the matched text with `\g<0>`:

```
>>> re.sub("{[^{}]+}", "A \g<0> B", "foo {} bar {baz}")
'foo {} bar A {baz} B'
```

So that's no problem. However, I'm stuck on how to trim the brackets from the referenced text. If I try applying a range to the replacement string:

```
>>> re.sub("{[^{}]+}", "\g<0>"[1:-1], "foo{}bar{baz}")
'foo{}barg<0'
```

The range is applied before the `\g<0>` is resolved to the matched text, and it trims the leading `\` and trailing `>`, leaving just `g<0`, which has no special meaning.

I also tried defining a function to perform the trimming:

```
def trimBraces(string):
    return string[1:-1]
```

But, unsurprisingly, that didn't change anything.

```
>>> re.sub("{[^{}]+}", trimBraces("\g<0>"), "foo{}bar{baz}")
'foo{}barg<0'
```

What am I missing here? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a *capturing group* to replace a part of the match:

```
>>> re.sub(r"{([^{}]+)}", r"\1", "foo{}bar{baz}")
'foo{}barbaz'
>>> re.sub(r"{([^{}]+)}", r"\1", "foo {} bar {baz}")
'foo {} bar baz'
```

Answer (score 2):

When you use `"\g<0>"[1:-1]` as a replacement pattern, you only slice the `"\g<0>"` *string*, not the actual value this backreference refers to.

If you need to use your "trimming" approach, you need to pass the match data object to the `re.sub`:

```
re.sub("{[^{}]+}", lambda m: m.group()[1:-1], "foo{}bar{baz}")
# => foo{}barbaz
```

See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/0mGwiL). Note that `m.group()` stands for the `\g<0>` in your pattern, i.e. the whole match value.

*However*, using [**capturing groups**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) is a more "organic" solution, see [alexce's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38734403/3832970).

Comment: Thanks for the extra info. It's always good to understand the concepts, not just know what works :)

Comment: Note that this solution is good when you want to trim a known number of chars from a string matched with more complex regex patterns with alternations (which would be a nice replacement for a missing branch reset feature in Python `re`). Say, you need to match substrings like `"..."` or `'...'` or `[....]` (but not `[..."` or `'...."`) and replace with what is inside these delimiters. In Python 2.x, `re.sub` will have issues with the backreference approach. Python 3.5 `re` handles that, `print(re.sub(r'"([^"]*)"|\'([^\']*)\'', r'\1\2', "'Something'"))` prints `Something` in Python 3.5.1.