# Speeding up text processing step

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I created a function that does some text processing on a dataframe of length `1045459`. It seems to be taking a longer than normal amount of time to compile.

This is what I did:

```
def clean_descriptions(text_list):
    
    # First get everything into lowercase
    text_list = str(text_list)
    for x in text_list:
        x = x.lower()
    
    # Remove all instances of 3 characters followed by a number
    for substr in re.findall(r'\W([A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]\d)\W', text_list):
        text_list = text_list.replace(substr, '')
    text_list = text_list.replace('[]','') 
        
    # Remove NA
    text_list = text_list.replace('NA','')
        
    return text_list
```

This is the way I am using the function:

```
df['short_description'] = clean_descriptions(df['short_description'].tolist())
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing the latter?

Here is an example of what the short_description looks like:

```
PRG2 - stelucie needs help with Radio
[VLR44] vlrd-fc-edg-fw-01-00-01:BGP Status - WARNING [DEEP-DIVE]
[LGB3] lgb3-ar-acc-sw172129.amazon.com:PSU Check
[BFI4] Walk Up Ticket - Other
[FC-OOB]-DMO3 is down [DEEP-DIVE]
```

Comment: pandas? what is `text_list`? list? dataframe? series?  Why not use pandas builtin regex and pandas functions to operate on the df`?

Comment: Why do you call `findall` then `replace` when you can use `re.sub` doing both at the same time?

Comment: @PatrickArtner I edited my question but yes I am using pandas dataframe, but I am probably doing something that is causing it to be super slow.

Comment: I think i have a more efficient solution to your problem, but do you have some sample input data w/ a desired output I could test it on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting yourself up for bad performance if you leave pandas to do this.

Use pandas own [replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) for *inplace* and *regex* syntax:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"short": ["Some text " + a + b + c + d + " more text" 
                             for a in "A"
                             for b in "DE"
                             for c in "1G"
                             for d in "2z"]})
print(df)

df["short"].replace(to_replace=r"(?i)(^|\W)([A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]\d)\W", value="", 
                    regex=True, inplace=True) # In Place - do not reassign else all None
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                      short
0  Some text AD12 more text
1  Some text AD1z more text
2  Some text ADG2 more text
3  Some text ADGz more text
4  Some text AE12 more text
5  Some text AE1z more text
6  Some text AEG2 more text
7  Some text AEGz more text

                      short
0  Some text AD12 more text
1  Some text AD1z more text
2        Some textmore text
3  Some text ADGz more text
4  Some text AE12 more text
5  Some text AE1z more text
6        Some textmore text
7  Some text AEGz more text
```

Comment: Using your function I still get instances of BHX4 (3 characters followed by a number) and those should be removed.

Comment: Let me edit my question to include a larger example if that works.

Comment: @Snorrlaxxx  for starters try using `r"(?i)(^|\W)([A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]\d)\W"`  - `(?i)` for case insensitivity and  `(^|\W)` optional for start of line or \W  should help. You can paste more of your data into https://regex101.com/  and fiddle with the regex pattern to get to something thats appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for the help, last question. If I wanted to remove strings that are contained in [] or () do you know how I would do that?

Comment: @Snorrlaxxx  [python-regex-replace-bracketed-text-with-contents-of-brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38734335/python-regex-replace-bracketed-text-with-contents-of-brackets)  - something like `r'(?i)(\[[a-z]{3}\d\])'` - prefix \ to make the [ and ] literal [] --> http://regex101.com is your friend

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace this part of your code:

```
for substr in re.findall(r'\W([A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]\d)\W', text_list):
        text_list = text_list.replace(substr, '')
```

Create a set (not a list) with all possible substrings so that it will be created only once and not each time that your function is called (1045459 times fro your dataframe).

Also replace your to_lower function (which is not correct by the way) simply by this:

```
text_list=text_list.lower()
```

Finally add all replacements to same command:

```
text_list = text_list.replace('[]','').replace('NA','')
```

Comment: If I create a set, I assume that would just contain the unique strings in the pandas dataframe column. From there how would I make the appropriate replacements? Perhaps a map?